# Select everything but a specific data set

Tags: javascript, select, d3.js, mouseover, selectall

I need to select everything excluding a data set I hover over, so far i have it so `this` is not selected but now i need to make it so `this` and everything with a common data set is not selected

```
.on("mouseover", function(d) {
    console.log(d);
    var circleUnderMouse = this;
    d3.selectAll(".dot").filter(function(d,i) {
        return (this !== circleUnderMouse);
    })
})
```

Comment: you can use :not selector d3.select("svg").selectAll("*:not(.dot)"); replace svg by ur rtto element

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `this`, you can use just the `datum` argument.

When you hover over a node...

> the specified listener will be evaluated for each selected element, being passed the current datum (d), the current index (i), and the current group (nodes), with this as the current DOM element.

So, to find all other elements with the same data, you can use only the first argument, which contains the *datum*, not *this*, which is the DOM element.

This is a demo to show you. We have a dataset with positions and a key named `type`:

```
var data = [{type: "foo", x: 30, y: 90},
    {type: "foo", x: 10, y: 50},
    //etc...
];
```

Hovering over a circle, we will select all other circles that don't share the same value for the `type` property, making them disappear:

```
circles.on("mouseover", function(d) {
    var filtered = circles.filter(function(e) {
        return e.type != d.type
    });
    filtered.attr("opacity", 0);
})
```

Here is the demo:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var data = [{
    type: "foo",
    x: 30,
    y: 90
}, {
    type: "foo",
    x: 10,
    y: 50
}, {
    type: "foo",
    x: 220,
    y: 130
}, {
    type: "baz",
    x: 40,
    y: 40
}, {
    type: "bar",
    x: 170,
    y: 20
}, {
    type: "baz",
    x: 220,
    y: 110
}, {
    type: "bar",
    x: 130,
    y: 120
}, {
    type: "foo",
    x: 150,
    y: 50
}, {
    type: "baz",
    x: 30,
    y: 110
}, {
    type: "foo",
    x: 100,
    y: 220
}];

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .domain(["foo", "bar", "baz"])
    .range(["teal", "brown", "gold"]);

var circles = svg.selectAll(".circles")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", d => d.x)
    .attr("cy", d => d.y)
    .attr("r", 8)
    .attr("fill", d => color(d.type));

circles.on("mouseover", function(d) {
    var filtered = circles.filter(function(e) {
        return e.type != d.type
    });
    filtered.attr("opacity", 0);
}).on("mouseout", function() {
    circles.attr("opacity", 1)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```